# How to reference one classes variable to another class for manipulation?

Tags: python

I have two classes, an "Items" class and a "Player" class.

- Player has "Health" and "Mana"
- The item class needs to change the players health or mana (depending on how it is defined), while retaining data of its own.

Basically, i want to make a method within the item class that activates the item to change the players health.

An idea of what I want my code to do, but have no idea how to:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,health,mana):
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana

class item:
    def __init__(self,classToEffect, EffectVariable, EffectAmount ):
        self.classToEffect = player
        self.EffectVariable = EffectVariable
        self.EffectAmount = EffectAmount

    def use(self):
        self.classToEffect.__dict__[self.EffectVariable] += EffectAmount

p1 = player(100,100)
i1 = item(p1,'health',10)

print(p1.health) # Should Print 100
i1.use() # Should increase p1.health by 10
print(p1.health) # Should print 110
```

When this is run i get a KeyError for 'health'.

Comment: Grammar nazi: your property should be called `class_to_affect`. ;)

Comment: lol, well i'll work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of types mate:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,health,mana):
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana

class item:
    def __init__(self, classToEffect, EffectVariable, EffectAmount ):
        self.classToEffect = classToEffect
        self.EffectVariable = EffectVariable
        self.EffectAmount = EffectAmount

    def use(self):
        self.classToEffect.__dict__[self.EffectVariable] += self.EffectAmount

p1 = player(100,100)
i1 = item(p1,'health',10)

print(p1.health) # Should Print 100
i1.use() # Should increase p1.health by 10
print(p1.health) # Should print 110
```

See:

`self.classToEffect = classToEffect`

and

`self.classToEffect.__dict__[self.EffectVariable] += self.EffectAmount`

Comment: Thank you, i just realized this as i was playing with my code! Works flawlessly now.